# Is there a suggested directory for packages like jre or JDK in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

A [atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/installing-jira-applications-on-linux-from-archive-file-938846844.html) post recommends this configuration for Installing Jira

```
jira.home=/var/jirasoftware-home
```

In accordance with [doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apcs02.html), `/opt` is for "Add-on application software packages". Additionally, some packages use `/var/opt` or `/var/lib`. Is there a suggested directory for packages like jre or JDK?